# Organic chemistry polymerisation

Tags: organic-chemistry, thermodynamics, experimental-chemistry, polymers

I have a doubt regarding the polymerisation of ethene, in the case of polymerisation, we basically are arranging the molecules in a systematic order and thus decreasing its entropy so shouldn't we be providing a low temperature in order to keep the process spontaneous...
Whereas, in reality the conditions for the reaction are high temperature and pressure?
Please help...

Comment: For a process to be spontaneous, the overral entropy of the univesrse should increase. Thus, the change in entropy of the system can be negative for a spontaneous process. At elevated temperatures, the spontaneity condition is still being met and additionally you are providing enough energy for bonds to break and reform between reactants.

Answer (score 1):

Rate of a reaction depends on the temperature conditions. So to make a reaction proceed significantly, we have to take the reactants up to the level of activation energy. One more thing to note here is that low temperature is not a fixed temperature, for example - consider 2 reactions A and B, now if low temperature for reaction A is 400 Kelvin, then it is certainly possible that for reaction B low temperature is say 800 Kelvin.

Comment: Spontaneous has a very specific meaning in thermodynamics - it is  process where the entropy change of the universe is positive. It is not related to the activation energy or the rate of reaction.

Comment: Why did you copy the question into a comment?

Comment: Please help me with this question. I am a bit doubtful about my previous answer.

Comment: Your answer is OK, removed dubious spontaneity. It's kinetic vs thermodynamic misunderstanding in question. Your kinetic info is ok